# Solution for saving a mediaplayer sound as ringtone

Tags: basic4android

I have some sounds playing in the app with the mediaplayer (MP.PLAY). Is their a solution or library to set a mediaplayer sound as a ringtone. I had seen an older post on b4a mentioning that it wasn't possible at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is still not possible (without creating a new library).